# Global operator has to be written very specifically, or else it won't be linked

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a custom random access iterator for a custom container. The iterator and container both work fine, but the annoying part is iterator comparison. If it is defined as such:

```
template <typename T>
class my_iterator {...}

template <typename T>
bool operator< (const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&) {...}
```

When I want to compare iterators, like in this situation:

```
for (my_iterator<T> i = foo.begin(); i < foo.end(); ++i) //Unresolved external error
```

I instead have to write:

```
for (my_iterator<T> i = foo.begin(); operator< <T>(i, foo.end()); ++i) //Looks weird
```

If I don't use the second way, it gives me a ridiculous unresolved external word vomit error.

How can I make it so that I can use the ordinary syntax for comparisons?

EDIT: I discovered what was causing the error, but I don't really understand why. The class looked like:

```
template <typename T>
class my_iterator {
    friend bool operator< (const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&);
};
```

My friend declaration was wrong and was supposed to be:

```
friend bool operator< <T>(const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&);
```

Why did the incorrect friend declaration work when the operator was written more like a function call, but not normally?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/SYBIKp) if I assemble these fragments into a test case. Please post a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your error, and the error message.

Comment: the idiom is `itr=begin(); itr!=end(); ++itr`. less is not defined for all iterators

Comment: I second that you should provide (have provided) the error message actually. Also, while they tend to be long-ish with complex templates, they still can be formatted in a readable way, just as a program can even if you stripped all unsignificant whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the template first so that the compiler knows that the friend `operator<` you declare at class scope is a template:

```
template <typename T>
class my_iterator;

template <typename T>
bool operator< (const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&);

template <typename T>
class my_iterator {
    // Note the "<>" here, this means "I'm a template"
    friend bool operator< <> (const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&);
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
bool operator< (const my_iterator<T>&, const my_iterator<T>&)
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, this gets parsed as a non-template friend function declaration (that you don't define), hence the linker errors. See http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends

Another option is to have a member `operator<`:

```
template <typename T>
class my_iterator {
    bool operator< (const my_iterator<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return this->impl < rhs.impl;
    }

    // ...
};
```